# Insert inline css/Style for If / else php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I need to style my table depending on the status. For example **Completed = Green** & **Pending = Orange**

PHP code. Its pulling the data from Mysql

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cashouts WHERE uid = ".$Auth->getLoggedId()." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $showPerPage");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
    {
    $username = $row->username;

    $amount = $row->amount;
    $status = $row->status;
    $method = $row->method;      
    $priority = $row->priority;          

    if($status == 'Complete' && !empty($row->payment_date))
    $date = date("d M, Y",strtotime($row->payment_date));    
    else
    $date = date("d M, Y",strtotime($row->request_date));


 $payments[] = array('date' => $date, 'amount' => $amount, 'method' => $method, 'status' => $status, 'cycle' => $priority);
```

}

My tpl/html file code

```
    <tbody>

    {if $payments ne ""}
    {foreach item=payment from=$payments}
    <tr>
    <td>{$payment.date}</td>
    <td>${$payment.amount}</td>
    <td>{$payment.method}</td>
    <td>{$payment.status}</td>
    <td>{$payment.cycle}</span></td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
    {/if}

    </tbody>
```

What i need is if status = Completed then

```
    <td style="color: Green;">{$payment.status}</td>
```

Else if status = Pending then

```
    <td style="color: Orange;">{$payment.status}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

add CASE in your SQL select statement.

```
CASE status
    WHEN 'Completed' THEN 'Green'
    WHEN 'Pending' THEN 'Orange'
    ELSE ''
End As color

$color = $row->color

<td style="color: {$payment.color};">{$payment.status}</td>
```